# How to debug failing react 16 components inside a jest snapshot test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Aloha,

I often get an error message when running a jest snapshot test where on sub component breaks. React itself writes the following warning, but keeps the thrown error message:

> An error was thrown inside one of your components, but React doesn't know what it was. This is likely due to browser flakiness. React does its best to preserve the "Pause on exceptions" behavior of the DevTools, which requires
>   some DEV-mode only tricks. It's possible that these don't work in your browser. Try triggering the error in production mode, or switching to a modern browser. If you suspect that this is actually an issue with React, please file an issue.

That message is not really useful and I was wondering if there is a certain environment variable I could set that would cause react to just pass the thrown error on.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, have you found the fix? @lumio

Comment: Try using an Enzyme shallow wrapper (`import {shallow} from 'enzyme'; ... const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);`) and rendering the snapshot using `wrapper.debug()`: `expect(wrapper.debug()).toMatchSnapshot();`

Comment: @Yawar ... that's a great idea, since the snapshot should only represent the current component. However if you want to test sub components, this might not work out that well

Comment: Ah, I see. Of course Enzyme can also do a deep render, but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: I'll check that out - thank you!